# How to create manage/server side commands?

Tags: meteor

Is there a way in Meteor, to add your own commands to the `meteor` command for the given project? So that on the server side you could have some commands similar to Django's manage commands. Like command for importing/updating data, maybe cron jobs, things like that? Thing is, I would like commands to have access to all the libraries and environment Meteor provides, especially so that I am sure that data stored in the database is compatible with Meteor.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment this isn't directly possible without an edit of meteor's source. If you're using meteorite you can have a localized meteor version which won't affect the rest of your meteor apps.

You might have to add a custom function over at `/tools/meteor.js` in this forked/modified meteor.

with:

```
Commands.push({
    name: "yourcustomcommand",
    help: "..",
    func: function (argv) {
        //Custom stuff
    });
```

Comment: Is there any other way where I could have a custom command? The issue is if I put any other code into project directory, it is bundled together and pushed to the client.

Comment: This looks like the only way for now theres no way to hook into the `Commands` from packages yet, Meteor's still young so it should come in. What I do instead is I make a custom meteor/method to usually do these on the server and then Meteor.call it when needed (with a password). This way nothing's sent to the client, the method's name is unknown to the client too

Comment: Is there a way to load Meteor libraries (for example, one to access MongoDB) in node.js application/script?